# Does every group homomorphism from $(0,\infty),\times)$ to $(\mathbb{R},+)$ send $1$ to $1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I just have some true/false questions I am revising with and I'm not sure about this.

Let $f:((0,\infty),\times)\to(\mathbb{R},+)$ be a group homomorphism, then $f(1)=1\tag{1}$

I know that a group homomorphism is when you have 2 groups $(G,*)$ and $(H,\odot)$ such that a function $f:G \to H$ gives $f(a*b)=f(a) \odot f(b)$ for all $a,b \in G$

If someone could explain that (or give me hint), it'd be awesome!

Okay actually as I was typing this I may have had an epiphony!

I think that (1)is  false because $1\times 1 \neq 1+1$

I also have,

Let $f:((0,\infty),\times)\to(\mathbb{R},+)$ be a group homomorphism, then $f(\frac{1}{2})=-f(2)\tag{2}$

But please don't tell me the answer to this one! I'll try figure it out based on feedback from the first one and go from there

Comment: inf u mean $\infty$@panderson

Comment: Thanks @David, have edited that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $(1)$ is not true. In general, given $f:G\rightarrow H$ group homomorphism, we know that the identity element $e_G\in G$ maps to the identity element $e_H \in H$.

You just need to identify these elements in your groups and substitute in
$$f(e_G)=e_H. \tag{1}$$

Then it should be easy to figure out $(2)$, since
$$f(1)=f\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\right) = f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + f(2).$$

Comment: so the first would be true if it were $f(1)=0$? and the second one is true because they are equivalent inverse functions?

Comment: @panderson Exactly. As you can see, the identity elements are not the same.

Comment: For the second one, use (1), $0=f(1)=f(1/2)+f(2)$ and now trivially $f(1/2) = -f(2)$.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $(G,\star)$ and $(H,\perp)$ are two groups and $f \, : \, G \, \rightarrow \, H$ a group homomorphism, then $f$ satisfies :

$$ \forall (x,y) \in G^{2}, \; f(x \star y) = f(x) \perp f(y) \tag{$\clubsuit$} $$

Letting $x=y=e_{G}$ in $(\clubsuit)$, we have :

$$ f(e_{G}) = f(e_{G}) f(e_{G}) $$

Since $f(e_{G}) \in H$, it has an inverse $\big( f(e_{G}) \big)^{-1}$ in $H$. Multiplying by $\big( f(e_{G}) \big)^{-1}$, we obtain :

$$f(e_{G}) = e_{H}. \tag{1}$$

As a consequence, let $x \in G$ and $y=x^{-1} \in G$. $(\clubsuit)$ gives :

$$ f(x \star x^{-1}) = f(e_{G}) = e_{H} = f(x) \perp f(x^{-1}) $$

Therefore :

$$ \forall x \in G, \, \big( f(x) \big)^{-1} = f(x^{-1}). \tag{2}$$

**Application** : let $G = (]0,+\infty[,\times)$ and $H = (\mathbb{R},+)$. Here, $e_{G} = 1$ and $e_{H} = 0$. $(1)$ writes :

$$ f(1) = 0. $$

And $(2)$ with $x=2 \in G$ writes :

$$ f(\underbrace{2^{-1}}_{\text{inverse in G}}) = f \Big( \frac{1}{2} \Big) = \underbrace{\big( f(2) \big)^{-1}}_{\text{inverse in H}} = - f(2). $$

Answer (score -1):

Use the same idea to view $\frac 1 2$ and $2$. 
Try to view this 
$$f(\frac  1 2)=f(\frac 1 4.2)=2\frac 1 4\tag 1$$
but $$ -f(2)=-f(\frac 1 2.4)=4\frac 1 2\tag 2$$ which is not same.

Comment: Why do you know that the image of $\frac{1}{4}.2$ is $2\frac 1 4$?

Comment: yes.. because $f(\frac 1 4.2)= \frac 1 4 +2=2\frac 1 4$ only know..@LeeKM

Comment: I guess what I mean is that the group operation is$+$ does not imply $f(\frac 1 4) = \frac 1 4$, am I right?

Comment: yes.......@LeeKM